# How to change YouTube thumbnail in Iframe? React

Tags: javascript, html, youtube, thumbnails

Is there any way to replace startin image (thumbnail) in YouTube video embded in iframe ?

I tried to find some solution but near everything from Internet seems to be outdated and not working.

Chat GPT says its literally impossible now, but i dont believe him :P

Its not my video so i cannot change it in YouTube account.